# what these lines are doing in python code?

Tags: python, request, formatting, telegram

I came across a python script online and there were some lines in the code that appeared to be some sort of formatting. But those lines don`t make any sense.Can anyone explain what they are.

```
{\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\cocoartf1671\cocoasubrtf400
{\fonttbl\f0\fswiss\fcharset0 Helvetica;}
{\colortbl;\red255\green255\blue255;}
{\*\expandedcolortbl;;}

\paperw11900\paperh16840\margl1440\margr1440\vieww10800\viewh8400
 \viewkind0

 \pard\tx566\tx1133\tx1700\tx2267\tx2834\tx3401\tx3968\tx4535
  \tx5102\tx5669\tx6236\tx6803\pardirnatural\partightenfactor0

\f0\fs24 \cf0 from time import sleep
\

\
import pyimgur
\
import requests
\
```

Comment: That looks like someone saved the Python script in RTF format instead of plain text.

Comment: You need to load it into an editor and re-save it to remove all the RTF markup.